# Should things like project IDs, cloud region IDs etc be kept secret on an open source project?

Tags: identity, opensource, github

All my side project are open source - just using the free Github account.

I'm wondering about how security conscious I need to be about keep things like:

- Google Cloud Platform Project IDs
- Log Rocket project IDs
- Logging email addresses

hidden on my commits.

And if they are something to be concerned about - what's the easiest way to manage them? If the stuff was solely in javascript, it's easy enough to keep it in a `config-secret.json` file  and add it to `.gitignore`. But I'm also using these values in yaml and bash script files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the underlying cloud providers are secure (meaning that they don't leak information from the IDs, or grant unauthorized access to change the project settings that they refer to), there's generally no real problem with the IDs being committed.  They disclose the fact that a service relationship exists, nothing more.  Of course, the rest of the code that interfaces via those IDs would also disclose that the relationship exists.

However, committing the logging email addresses is an issue.  If those email addresses are leaked, and there's enough information committed around them to reconstruct the form of the logs, it increases the risk of processing if the sender of the logs doesn't properly sign them with DKIM or such, and/or if the recipient doesn't verify that signature before acting on them.  Note that you can't really trust email logs without verifying them, regardless; because email addresses are also subject to receiving unsolicited and unwanted messages, you could end up processing some email of an improper form if you're not careful.  The probability of having to deal with such also goes up when you commit the email address into a public repository.  (If you want to test your ability to properly handle undesired submissions to that email address, by all means.  But you could also test that by sending to that email address from unapproved submission email addresses as well.)

As always, the ultimate decision to do such should be firmly rooted in your security policy, which is necessarily based on your threat assessments and mitigation strategies for those threats.  Anybody here can only express their thoughts based on their own understandings of the issues involved, and nobody here has any idea what your threat mitigation strategies are -- or even what they should be based on information that only you have.  Make wise decisions, which almost certainly don't include "accepting and acting on the word of random StackExchange members with no additional critical thought".

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that these Yaml and bash script files are part of the open source project. How about writing a script that will replace those values, push your changes to the server, and then replaces the values back for you. You can replace the values with comments identifying what needs to be placed there.

Comment: Welcome to Security. I encourage you to expand your answer with an example or two because it can be a great answer to the OP's hassle. I would use placeholders in system variables, for example

Comment: Let me look into this, I am not super proficient in bash but dont mind the challenge, I can also write a javascript program to do this too if the OP wants that as well